# Module is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

Hello fri i have created a new projects and i have created a new demo page

See to my coding in plunker i have created all code in plunker

**[link here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z6YWL6Q9HOUoWCZZqSNB?p=preview)**

Problum is i have create a demo page check to header.html

```
<a ui-sref="rohit-about">about</a>
<a ui-sref="home">home</a>
```

if i click to about than show this error

```
Error: Could not resolve 'rohit-about' from state 'index'
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3074)
    at Object.go (angular-ui-router.js:3007)
    at angular-ui-router.js:4057
    at angular.js:17105
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5073)
    at angular.js:5335
```

can u please cehck to my code and tell me where i m wrong writing my code .

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the double definition of the MAIN app module: **`.module('azadApp', [...])`**

The first in `app.js`:

```
// Code goes here

angular
    .module('azadApp', [
            // here type dependency
            'rohit.about',
            'rohit.usdk'
        ]);
```

The Second in `rohit-module/layout/js/module.js`:

```
// another file and/or another anonymous function
(function(){
 // using the function form of use-strict...
  'use strict';

  angular.module('azadApp', ['ui.router']);


})();
```

And in fact, the second definition is *killing* the first. So there is no `'rohit.about'` at the end in the `'azadaApp'`. Because the definition in the *app.js* is beated. Just remove the second, or set it properly...